# What is equivalent of JVM class loader in C#?

Tags: java, .net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Equivalent of Class Loaders in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185836/equivalent-of-class-loaders-in-net)
>   [.NET Class Loader - What is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947223/net-class-loader-what-is-it)

I am from C# background, and beginning to learn java. I am having a hard time understanding class loaders - hierarchy , scope, bootloader, etc. 
Is there an equivalent technology in C# .NET, which I can refer to help me understand the java class loader concept?