# How classes are loaded by .Net?

Tags: c#, java, .net, vb.net, class

As some of us know the java classes are loaded by the `ClassLoader`. However, I don't know what .NET uses to load classes. What does it use? I've researched through Google, and still nothing.

Comment: add assemblyresolver,  Activator.createinstance to your search phrase in google. remember it is not just c# but add .net as this is common framework functionality

Comment: Answer can be found here, long read though

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185836/equivalent-of-class-loaders-in-net

Answer (score 1):

In .NET assemblies are the fundamental unit of deployment. The technology that actually loads the assemblies is called Fusion. For more details on that read the .NET Fusion Workshop. Each assembly has its own class loader to load types from that assembly.
Hosting the Common Language Runtime may also be of interest.